Microsoft Excel (on Mac) pivot table "Filter -> By label" stopped working properly
I rely on Excel pivot tables for quick data analysis. Recently I noticed that the Filter -> By label treats all columns in the pivot table as Date! For example previously, if the column had only text, when I was clicking on Filter -> By label I would see these filters:

But now regardless of data type in the column I always see these filters which are basically for Date type only:

I tried many things including reinstalling Excel and removing all the *Office* directories under ~/Library/Group Containers but the issue didn't go away.
Any help to resolve the issue is appreciated.

The issue is fixed in version 16.86. As of today the latest released version is 16.85. To update to version 16.86 you need to get the "Insider builds" following instructions here: https://insider.microsoft365.com/en-us/join/mac
